# "Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)" in reference to a document that was just created

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script creates a document, stores the document url in a cell on the spreadsheet, then another function opens said document using that url. I am getting the "Document is missing" error about 70% of the time I attempt to run it. Any ideas? the failure is on line 52.

```js
function resultsDoc() {
  var ssa = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = ssa.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();


  var ui = ssa.getUi();


  var doca = DocumentApp;
  var drive = DriveApp;
  var template = "1uSCtqPwDYM-AtGAu3kzv3ZD0jdXnl12GxmdF_BDNb-M";
  var source = doca.openById(template);
  var resDocCopy = drive.getFileById(template).makeCopy('Tournament Results');
  var resDocId = resDocCopy.getId();
  var resDoc = doca.openById(resDocId);
  var docBody = resDoc.getBody();
  var resDocUrl = resDoc.getUrl();
  sheets.shift();
  for (var dis in sheets) {
    var thisSheet = sheets[dis];
    var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "f"];
    var disLetter = letters[dis];
    var eventa = thisSheet.getName();
    var aOne = thisSheet.getRange('B3').getValue() + "  " + thisSheet.getRange('A3').getValue();
    var aTwo = thisSheet.getRange('B4').getValue() + "  " + thisSheet.getRange('A4').getValue();
    var aThree = thisSheet.getRange('B5').getValue() + "  " + thisSheet.getRange('A5').getValue();
    var aFour = thisSheet.getRange('B6').getValue() + "  " + thisSheet.getRange('A6').getValue();
    var aFive = thisSheet.getRange('B7').getValue() + "  " + thisSheet.getRange('A7').getValue();
    var aSix = thisSheet.getRange('B8').getValue() + "  " + thisSheet.getRange('A8').getValue();

    docBody.replaceText('<<' + disLetter + '>>', eventa);
    docBody.replaceText('<<' + disLetter + '1>>', aOne);
    docBody.replaceText('<<' + disLetter + '2>>', aTwo);
    docBody.replaceText('<<' + disLetter + '3>>', aThree);
    docBody.replaceText('<<' + disLetter + '4>>', aFour);
    docBody.replaceText('<<' + disLetter + '5>>', aFive);
    docBody.replaceText('<<' + disLetter + '6>>', aSix);

  }
  ss.insertSheet("Links");
  var linksSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Links");
  linksSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue("Link to results page:");
  linksSheet.getRange(2, 1).setValue(resDocUrl);
  Utilities.sleep(9000);

}

function sweepsDoc() {
  var doca = DocumentApp;
  var linksSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Links");
  var resDocUrl = linksSheet.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var resDoc = doca.openByUrl(resDocUrl);
  var docBody = resDoc.getBody();

  var sweepsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sweeps');

  docBody.replaceText("<<sweeps1>>", sweepsSheet.getRange('B2').getValue());
  docBody.replaceText("<<sweeps2>>", sweepsSheet.getRange('B3').getValue());
  docBody.replaceText("<<sweeps3>>", sweepsSheet.getRange('B4').getValue());


}
```

Comment: If you are not familiar with `Logger.log()` then please read the [Link to troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)  Log the value of `resDocUrl`

Comment: Did you provide a valid working doc url?

Comment: The logger logs the correct url.

Comment: And the provided url does work - I can click it to access the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright - so I figured out a "workaround" more than an actual solution. Instead of storing and accessing the document Url, I switched over to using the document's Id. 
While I still don't understand why the Url causes it to lose track of the document, using the Id has 100% success rate over 20 attempts, while using the Url only had a 10% success rate over 20. 
If you know what the problem with using the Url is, please let me know. If you're having the same problem, switch your code to use the doc id.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think not saving the document could be causing the problem.

Add the line below to the end of your code that builds the doc.

```
resDoc.saveAndClose();
```

Comment: That was a great thought - I believed it may work, but I'm still getting the same issue. Thanks for trying!